# Show var if item doesn't match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, indexing

I'm using Feedburner to show feeds. Sometimes the feeds have the same text. I would like to 'hide' any 'duplicates' of a certain feed. I have wrapped the feedburner script inside a div 'unique' like this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHEKd/3/)

I have set display:none for the feeds because I only want to show the feeds which match the 'index'. I don't understand why the var is not 'showing'

Comment: @mplungjan That is not the case (How did you figure that...?)

Comment: I Missed the ( from makeArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `.text()` query is incorrect.

```
var a = $('.unique a').text();
```

The above returns just text:

> Man dood na val in liftschacht RotterdamBulgarije geeft foto vrij van
>   tweede verdachte bomaanslagStraat ontruimd bij grote brand
>   OverdinkelAsiel Assange verandert niets voor LondenMoordenaar
>   honkballer Halman op vrije voetenGrote brand in Overdinkel'Broer
>   vermoorde honkballer ontoerekeningsvatbaar'Boete voor RET om
>   studentenreisgegevensDode bij crash vliegtuigje BiddinghuizenMinder
>   tienermoeders dan ooit in Nederland

There is nothign in `a` to iterate through.

I think you may be wanting to do:

```
var a = $('.unique a');
```

This returns a list of items you can iterate over now.

The next issue I can see is that your filter method simply iterates through the array of 12 items and still return the same 12 items, the item at the index will always match the current item.

Try this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $a = $('.unique a');
    var unique = {};

    for (i = 0; i < $a.length; i++) {
        var itemText = $($a[i]).text();
        if (unique[itemText]) {
            $($a[i]).remove();
        }
        else {
            unique[itemText] = true;
        }
    };

    $('.unique').show();
});
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/82Q4x/)

I declared `unique` as an object. This object will keep a record of each anchor text value we already processed by adding the `itemtext` as a property assigning the of `true`. This is possible due to the dynamic nature of JavaScript which allows you to assign proeprties to an object on the fly.

> Boete voor RET om studentenreisgegevens **true**,
>   Bulgarije geeft afbeelding vrij van verdachte aanslag **true**,
>   Ecuador verleent Wikileaks-baas Julian Assange politiek asiel **true**

When calling `unique[itemText]` we are asking the `unique` object to give us value of the property with the name matching what is in `itemText`.

If the property exists the value `true` is returned as that is the value we assign to the property. We will now remove the value from the source as we already processed it.
If the property is not found then `undefined` is returned and we add the property dynamically to the `unique` object assigning it the value of `true`.

With the source now stripped of the duplicates we make the container visible again.

Comment: Thank you so much(: And thanks even more for explaining what is going on +10